# Webfont Loader Issue Deploying Gatsby to Netlify

Tags: webpack, deployment, webfonts, gatsby, netlify

Just getting started with Gatsby + Netlify. Building off the [Netlify Starter Blog theme](https://gatsby-starter-blog-demo.netlify.com/), but stripping out the default NPM-installed fonts and wanting to host my own. Put `woff` files in `src/components/fonts` and `fonts.css` in `src/components`. Doing `import './fonts.css'` in `Layout.js` above `import ./layout.css`. Looks great on local, deploy to Netlify fails with log below.

Did NPM install of the `gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader` per their [guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader/) and added:

```
{
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-web-font-loader`,
      options: {
        custom: {
          families: [`ArtifexCF`, `Boston`],
          urls: [`src/components/fonts.css`]
        }
      }
    }
```

Still getting this when pushing to Gitlab. Breaking when it hits my fonts.css. Any help?

```
11:48:52 AM: build-image version: 84aca9ba39e0ee86ba194760fbfc51a808f62543
11:48:52 AM: buildbot version: 57d44fd1631cc3fff8b38fbaf88d3d04f946418a
11:48:52 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:48:52 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:48:52 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:48:53 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:48:53 AM: git clone git@gitlab.com:smallreflection/impossible-possibility
11:48:55 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:48:56 AM: Starting build script
11:48:56 AM: Installing dependencies
11:48:57 AM: Downloading and installing node v8.15.0...
11:48:57 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.15.0/node-v8.15.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
11:48:57 AM:   0.0%
11:48:57 AM: 
####
11:48:57 AM:                                  6.9%
11:48:58 AM: 
#####################################
11:48:58 AM:                                 52.5%
11:48:58 AM: 
######################################
11:48:58 AM: ################################## 100.0%
11:48:58 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
11:48:58 AM: Checksums matched!
11:49:00 AM: Now using node v8.15.0 (npm v6.4.1)
11:49:00 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.3.6, read from environment
11:49:02 AM: Using ruby version 2.3.6
11:49:02 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
11:49:02 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
11:49:02 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
11:49:02 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.4.1
11:49:11 AM: npm
11:49:11 AM:  WARN deprecated circular-json@0.3.3: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
11:50:00 AM: > sharp@0.21.3 install /opt/build/repo/node_modules/sharp
11:50:00 AM: > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
11:50:00 AM: info
11:50:00 AM:  sharp Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.0/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
11:50:05 AM: > cwebp-bin@5.0.0 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/cwebp-bin
11:50:05 AM: > node lib/install.js
11:50:05 AM:   ✔ cwebp pre-build test passed successfully
11:50:05 AM: > mozjpeg@6.0.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/mozjpeg
11:50:05 AM: > node lib/install.js
11:50:06 AM:   ✔ mozjpeg pre-build test passed successfully
11:50:06 AM: > pngquant-bin@5.0.1 postinstall /opt/build/repo/node_modules/pngquant-bin
11:50:06 AM: > node lib/install.js
11:50:06 AM:   ✔ pngquant pre-build test passed successfully
11:50:11 AM: npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
11:50:11 AM: npm WARN eslint-config-react-app@3.0.6 requires a peer of eslint@5.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
11:50:11 AM: npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules/fsevents):
11:50:11 AM: npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
11:50:11 AM: added 2008 packages from 1192 contributors and audited 24956 packages in 68.565s
11:50:11 AM: found 0 vulnerabilities
11:50:12 AM: NPM modules installed
11:50:12 AM: Started restoring cached go cache
11:50:12 AM: Finished restoring cached go cache
11:50:12 AM: unset GOOS;
11:50:12 AM: unset GOARCH;
11:50:12 AM: export GOROOT='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.10.linux.amd64';
11:50:12 AM: export PATH="/opt/buildhome/.gimme/versions/go1.10.linux.amd64/bin:${PATH}";
11:50:12 AM: go version >&2;
11:50:12 AM: export GIMME_ENV='/opt/buildhome/.gimme/env/go1.10.linux.amd64.env';
11:50:12 AM: go version go1.10 linux/amd64
11:50:12 AM: Installing missing commands
11:50:12 AM: Verify run directory
11:50:12 AM: Executing user command: gatsby build
11:50:14 AM: success open and validate gatsby-configs — 0.011 s
11:50:15 AM: success load plugins — 0.334 s
11:50:16 AM: success onPreInit — 1.084 s
11:50:16 AM: success delete html and css files from previous builds — 0.132 s
11:50:16 AM: success initialize cache — 0.014 s
11:50:16 AM: success copy gatsby files — 0.038 s
11:50:16 AM: success onPreBootstrap — 0.006 s
11:50:16 AM: success source and transform nodes — 0.115 s
11:50:17 AM: success building schema — 0.376 s
11:50:17 AM: success createPages — 0.057 s
11:50:17 AM: success createPagesStatefully — 0.040 s
11:50:17 AM: success onPreExtractQueries — 0.004 s
11:50:17 AM: success update schema — 0.190 s
11:50:17 AM: success extract queries from components — 0.147 s
11:50:17 AM: success run graphql queries — 0.176 s — 7/7 40.16 queries/second
11:50:17 AM: success write out page data — 0.003 s
11:50:17 AM: success write out redirect data — 0.001 s
11:50:17 AM: done generating icons for manifest
11:50:17 AM: success onPostBootstrap — 0.099 s
11:50:17 AM: info bootstrap finished - 5.379 s
11:50:31 AM: error Generating JavaScript bundles failed
11:50:31 AM: 
11:50:31 AM:   Error: ./src/components/fonts.css
11:50:31 AM:   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.j  s):
11:50:31 AM:   ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './fonts/boston-we  b/Boston-Semibold.woff' in '/opt/build/repo/src/components'
11:50:31 AM:       at factory.create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js  :823:10)
11:50:31 AM:       at factory (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.j  s:397:22)
11:50:31 AM:       at resolver (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.  js:130:21)
11:50:31 AM:       at asyncLib.parallel (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModul  eFactory.js:224:22)
11:50:31 AM:       at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:2825:7
11:50:31 AM:       at /opt/build/repo/node_modules/neo-async/async.js:6886:13
11:50:31 AM:       at normalResolver.resolve (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/webpack/lib/Normal  ModuleFactory.js:214:25)
11:50:31 AM:       at doResolve (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resolver.j  s:184:12)
11:50:31 AM:       at hook.callAsync (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resol  ver.js:238:5)
11:50:31 AM:       at _fn0 (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCode  Factory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
11:50:31 AM:       at resolver.doResolve (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/U  nsafeCachePlugin.js:37:5)
11:50:31 AM:       at hook.callAsync (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resol  ver.js:238:5)
11:50:31 AM:       at _fn0 (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCode  Factory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
11:50:31 AM:       at hook.callAsync (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/Resol  ver.js:238:5)
11:50:31 AM:       at _fn0 (eval at create (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCode  Factory.js:32:10), <anonymous>:12:1)
11:50:31 AM:       at resolver.doResolve (/opt/build/repo/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/D  escriptionFilePlugin.js:42:38)
11:50:31 AM:    @ ./src/components/Layout.js 5:0-21
11:50:31 AM:    @ ./src/templates/blog-post.js
11:50:31 AM:    @ ./.cache/async-requires.js
11:50:31 AM:    @ ./.cache/production-app.js
11:50:31 AM: 
11:50:31 AM: Caching artifacts
11:50:31 AM: Started saving node modules
11:50:31 AM: Finished saving node modules
11:50:31 AM: Started saving pip cache
11:50:31 AM: Finished saving pip cache
11:50:31 AM: Started saving emacs cask dependencies
11:50:31 AM: Finished saving emacs cask dependencies
11:50:31 AM: Started saving maven dependencies
11:50:31 AM: Finished saving maven dependencies
11:50:31 AM: Started saving boot dependencies
11:50:31 AM: Finished saving boot dependencies
11:50:31 AM: Started saving go dependencies
11:50:31 AM: Finished saving go dependencies
11:50:32 AM: Cached node version v8.15.0
11:50:32 AM: Error running command: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:50:32 AM: Failing build: Failed to build site
11:50:32 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:50:32 AM: Finished processing build request in 1m39.926023356s
```

Comment: Have you tried the build locally to try to see where the error is coming from? It looks like you are missing `src/components/fonts/boston-web/Boston-Semibold.woff`

Comment: Oh man. Seems like it was a simple capitalization error (`Semibold` instead of `SemiBold`). Fixed and live!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all paths are correct in `src/components/fonts.css`

These paths should be relative paths to `src/components`, since this is the location of the `fonts.css` file.

***Extra:*** There are some great [libraries for the open source fonts](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces/tree/master/packages) out there you can use with Gatsby to host your own fonts without having to manage all the assets yourself. This method does not require the font loader in Gatsby.

Pick a font [from the list](https://github.com/KyleAMathews/typefaces/tree/master/packages) (for example roboto)

```
$ yarn add typeface-roboto

import 'typeface-roboto'
```